# How to change GSettings without X11 running?

Tags: d-bus, gsettings

I have an installation script that customises the target machine by running about two-dozen `gsettings set` commands. Trouble is, that only works if you run the command as the right user. If you run it as root, it doesn't work at all.

So I invented a script function that looks like this:

```
function GSET
{
    echo "gsettings set '$1' '$2' '$3'"
    sudo -u mango dbus-launch gsettings set "$1" "$2" "$3"
}
```

The script then calls this function several dozen times, which seems to work (i.e., the settings actually change now), and all is good.

Well, not quite: If I run this on the machine I'm trying to configure, it seems to work great. If I try to run it on our build server in a `chroot` environment to create an installation image... The server now has a dozen `dbus-daemon` processes running on it. And every time I run a new installation build, I'm left with more and more of these useless processes running, until eventually the server exhausts some kind of resource (PIDs or something), and `gsettings` stops working completely.

So, my question: What is the *correct* way to make `gsettings` work? I saw another answer somewhere that suggested adding the `--exit-with-session` switch, but that just stopped the command working at all. Is there some way to launch a single daemon for all the settings and then stop it afterwards or something?

Comment: It's not clear what's your actual goal but you're doing it wrong imo, it looks like a XY question to me (I might be wrong though...). Anyway, I suggest reading [Manage user and system settings with dconf](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf/SystemAdministrators)

Comment: Could this help you? https://askubuntu.com/questions/276509/change-gsettings-without-running-x-and-unity

Comment: @JBoyAdvance I tried the exit-with-session thing; it just made the changes no longer take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, `dbus-launch` creates a new D-Bus daemon every time it is run.  You can instead use `dbus-launch` and kill it when you are done:

```
# Make the function
GSET () {
    sudo -u mango DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" gsettings set "$1" "$2" "$3"
}
# Launch the daemon
. <(sudo -u mango dbus-daemon --sh-syntax)
# Run as many commands as you need
GSET x1 y1 z1
GSET x2 y2 z2
...
# Kill the daemon
sudo -u mango kill "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID"
```

---

You could use a shell-based transactional approach to avoid calling `sudo` repeatedly.  Something like:

```
script=$(mktemp gset-transaction.XXXXXXXXXX)
create_transaction () {
    printf '. <(dbus-launch --sh-syntax)\n' > "$script"
}
GSET () {
    printf 'gsettings set "%s" "%s" "%s"\n' "$1" "$2" "$3" >> "$script"
}
commit_transaction () {
    printf 'kill "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID"\n' >> "$script"
    sudo -u mango bash -c "$script"
    # optionally:
    # rm "$script"
}

create_transaction
GSET x1 y1 z1
GSET x2 y2 z2
...
commit_transaction
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me *finally* fix this infuriating problem... Here, have some rep.